# How to correctly copy and paste programming code from PDF to editors?

Tags: pdf, text-editors, visual-studio

I'm reading a pdf book that contains programming code, when I copy the code and past it in, say visual studio, the doulbe quotation marks changes from this(**"**) to this (**”**) which leads to syntax errors.
How can I fix this?

Comment: What programming language are you using that uses **"** instead quotation marks?

Comment: All programming languages I know uses hte double quotation marks(")
C++, Java, C#, JavaScript, etc...

Comment: Which is my point.  Your saying when you copy the text **"** is being changed to a quotation mark.

Comment: First thank you for trying to help.
What happens is when I copy this (") and paste it in the editor I get this(”).

Comment: Try to paste to Notepad first?

Comment: I still don't understand that problem **”** isn't the correct character a double quotation mark is **"** I am not even sure what ( **”** ) is exactly because its not a double quotation mark ( **"** ).

Comment: @SPRBRN
I tried but with the same result!!

Comment: @Ramhound
This is what I want ( " ).
This is what I get ( ” ).
 And I don't know why.

Comment: What you get is a double quotation mark which should be correct.  Is this book perhaps not in English because like I said I don't even know what the character your trying to copy is.

Comment: Maybe the font used in the PDF shows " but still it's the curled version when pasted in another font? So maybe the problem is not the pasting, but the source. Try another PDF reader. You might try Firefox, which has bad PDF rendering, but it may make things clear. https://pdfreaders.org/

Comment: @SPRBRN
I tried Firefox with no hope, but your explanation make sense.

Comment: Maybe if the font changed as @SPRBRN said this problem will be fixed.
This http://goo.gl/6JM73V article shows how to change the font in the adobe reader premium.
Unfortunately I only have the free version, so I can't try it now.

Comment: Maybe the publisher can fix it? I think they made a mistake. I've done this one time with O'Reilly and they fixed the book within a week.

Comment: Does this happen with a specific book, or books from the same publisher? If so, it is very likely that the original text in the book uses smart quotes (which means that the publisher did a very lousy job, IMHO). In this case, you'd have to get to the publisher to have things fixed. On the other end, there are text editors which have a "uneducate quotes" function (BBEdit, for example does).

Comment: @Baso: Changing fonts does not change anything; the character code for the straight quote and the curly quotes is different. Also, there is no product named "Adobe Reader Premium". There is Adobe Reader, and then there is Adobe Acrobat (Pro).

Comment: @MaxWyss
It doesn't happen with every book, but it did happen with more than one and from different publishers. 
PS: I meant the "Adobe Acrobat(Pro)" instead of "Adobe Reader Premium".
Thanks for the help.

Comment: OK, have you checked whether the text editor you are using has an automatic smarten quote setting? Or do you by chance have some "smart" autocorrect utilities on your system?